# can we able to create multiple deployments from single devops repositary, for multiple web apps

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-devops, devops, devops-services

I had a python, PHP, database data. Can we deploy those to web apps by using a single DevOps repository?  but need to deploy them on multiple web apps in azure portal .or we need to create an individual repository for each code?

Comment: Are you looking for Release Pipeline: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at this in 2 ways :

- Have different artifacts : with the same ci pipeline, create multiple artifacts, that will create multiple releases for. That would be your deployments.
- Have everything in Yaml pipelines (CI and CD), and deploy wiht multiple steps.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to define multiple [stages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) in release pipeline to create multiple deployments. Stages are the major divisions in your release pipeline: "run functional tests", "deploy to pre-production", and "deploy to production" are good examples of release stages. A stage in a release pipeline consists of jobs and tasks. Check the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/define-multistage-release-process?view=azure-devops

Comment: in this case, do I need to create individual repositories for all of my codes?

Comment: You could add multiple artifacts in release pipeline: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops.